# how to get a A SUGGESTION, not just a word in python

Tags: python, random

i have a list of suggestion parsed from json which look likes `['just a suggestion', 'and this too suggestion', 'dont care, this suggestion']`

and i write this code:

```
import json
import random
import dpath.util as dp

with open('.logs') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    res = dp.values(data, "/posts/*/com")
    file = open(".text", "w")
    file.write(str(res))
    file.close()
    file = open(".text", "r")
    tt = file.read()
    text = random.choice(tt.split())
    print(text)
```

but, this give to me only words. something like `care` or another word from list. how do i get a random suggestion from a list?

Comment: Replace ``ts.split()`` with ``tt``.

Comment: How will it help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What kind of output would you like to see instead?

Comment: Jasmijn i need to get something like `just a suggestion`, not a `just` or another word from suggestion

Comment: Raymond Hettinger then i will get just a letter, not a word or a suggestion

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "i have a list of suggestion parsed from json " Okay; I see that you have put this into the variable `data`. Next, we produce some kind of data structure that is a subset of the data, and... convert it into a string? And then write it to a file? And then read the string back from the same file? And then re-parse it with our own code? I can't understand the thought process behind this. What exactly do you think is the *purpose* of JSON, anyway?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IIUC you have a string read from a file that you want to treat like a
list so you need:

```
import ast
(...)
l = ast.literal_eval(tt)
text = random.choice(l)
print(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you don't need this temporary file, and you could just do:

```
import json
import random
import dpath.util as dp

with open('.logs') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    res = dp.values(data, "/posts/*/com")
    text = random.choice(res)
    print(text)
```

Comment: but, i need to parse certain strings from json into another txt file.

Comment: **Why**? Did you **try to check** what `res` contains? What does it contain? What do you think it should contain instead, and how is that different? Did you **try the code** shown here? Do you get the right result? If you get the wrong result, how is it wrong?